# Test data for spatial search unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, geospatial, sample-data

I'm looking for a small database (e.g. 50 addresses) of US postal addresses with ZIP codes,
and if possible, a distance between each one for the spatial search engine unit tests.

Do you know where I can get such a database?

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look for some famous locations (e.g. Statue of Liberty or some museums) on Google Maps. You'll get an address, then you may check a distance to any other place.

Automating this task should be easy via Google Maps API and you can get even bigger database than 50 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

you can make spatial data by yourself. Here is a list of websites which help you: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/628/convert-address-to-spatial-data-geocoding-for-sql-server-r2